# What is a valid use case for using a Non-Equi Join? >, >=, <, <=, <>

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, join

What is the purpose of using Operators in the FROM Statement? Most examples provided on the internet can be solved by putting similar criteria in the WHERE statement.

Example:

```
SELECT T1.OrderNum, T1.SpecialOfferAppliedDate AS SOAD, T1.SpecialOfferID, T2.StartDate, T2.EndDate
FROM OrderDetail AS T1 
   INNER JOIN SpecialOffer AS T2 
        ON T1.SpecialOfferID = T2.SpecialOfferID 
       AND T1.SOAD < T2.EndDate 
       AND T1.SOAD >= T2.StartDate
```

Example using the WHERE Statement:

```
SELECT T1.OrderNum, T1.SpecialOfferAppliedDate AS SOAD, T1.SpecialOfferID, T2.StartDate, T2.EndDate
FROM OrderDetail AS T1 
  INNER JOIN SpecialOffer AS T2 
          ON T1.SpecialOfferID = T2.SpecialOfferID 
WHERE T1.SOAD < T2.EndDate 
  AND T1.SOAD >= T2.StartDate
```

EDIT: Is there any query someone can provide where I would HAVE to join by a Non-Equi Join? At this point it seems to only be relevant on: personal preference OR performance increase on HUGE tables

Comment: It would make more sense to use the first form if it was a `left join` because using the `where clause` like that (not accounting for `null` values) would turn it into an `inner join`.

Comment: The title of the question does not appear to have anything to do with the actual question...?

Comment: why is `WHERE` more valid than `ON`?

Comment: @Brandon Please review the query. An Equal Join means that there may be a record to retrieve in a similar table. The first query example i provided contains some symbols of a Non-Equi Join, a.k.a. >, >=, <, <=, <>

Comment: Checking for inequality is common in recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs). The recursive `SELECT` often excludes processing rows that are identical to the row under consideration using something like `on ... and CTE.Id <> Table.Id`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the day, SQL 2005 and earlier it used to be depending on how SQL Server was maintained it could be claimed that it was slightly faster at times.  I got used to doing it this way as it made logical sense to me to limit scope faster and go for the biggest tables first and get more bang for the buck.

EG: Say I have three tables A, B, C.  And A and B had MILLIONS of rows and some indexes on a Dt(Date) field.  And the other table had only a few ten thousand rows.  I would a lot of times do something like this:

```
Select (columns)
From a
     inner join b on a.Id = b.FId
         and a.Id >= (somedate)
     inner join c on b.Id = c.FId
```

It generally to me made more sense to limit scope as soon as possible and in terms of the engine the 'From' statement actually comes first in a SQL Server engine from what I have read and seen.  So I was really taking a set of saying all the potentials of millions upon millions THEN doing a where statement to just knowing that an inner join is always saying the requirements MUST match to return and limiting scope further.  The 'Where' clause does do the same thing but is evaluated AFTER the 'From' statement so it was reasonable to conclude it would be slower.

However there is the constant debate in dev circles of performance versus readability.  So if I had something like:

```
Select (columns)
From a
     inner join b on a.Id = b.FId
         and a.Id >= (somedate)
         and a.ocol = (criteria)
     left outer join c on b.Id = c.FId
where c.ocol = (criteria)
```

Someone could tell me: "Hey man you are only getting a performance of 0.00001 boost from that, how about just putting it all in the Where clause?"  It is sometimes a balancing act for performance versus readability.  If something is highly lagging though I could rightfully say it may be better a certain way.  However in general I read that around 2012, or maybe 2008 R2, or so Microsoft reworked the engine that it compiles more efficient anyways that essentially it no longer really saves time.  You can test it yourself though if you want:

Run this on SQL Management Studio:

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

And you will see things like this:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 8 ms.
```

On the Messages tab.  You can also of course do the more heavy handed 'Client Statistics' tab from the view panel and see even more detail.  Suffice to say it is just a syntactic trick employed by many to make more efficient use of the engine execution to limit scope faster.  However the reworking may not make it any better any more.  I still use it though when coding on my own and you get used to things :)

Answer (score 2):

*All* joins can be rewritten with WHERE statements doing all the work.

```
SELECT table1.cols ..., table2.cols ... 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON TRUE
WHERE table1.id = table2.id 

UNION SELECT cols, null ... -- for LEFT or FULL JOIN
FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)

UNION SELECT null ..., cols -- for RIGHT or FULL JOIN
FROM table2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)
```

Note how the `LEFT | RIGHT | FULL JOIN` cases are more unwieldy when you use `WHERE`

I personally much prefer expressing *the relationship in question* in the `JOIN ... ON` rather than the `WHERE` clause. In your example that can be called "the special offers that apply to this order", where "apply to this order" has both a identity and temporal component.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about readability and intelligibility.

When you join two tables together, it makes sense to keep the logic of that join in one place. In your example, the logic matching records relies both on a foreign key relationship (`T1.SpecialOfferID = T2.SpecialOffID`) and the dates of the purchase and special offer. The date logic appears integral to the join - you only want to retrieve matches that fit within that date range.

In the "where" clause, you might have other limitations which don't affect the joining logic - the value of the order, the creator of the special offer, whatever.

It is usually a question of interpretation which clause is an inherent part of the join, and which is a refinement on the data set. In practical terms, the two usages are equivalent.

The "non-equi" part is - I believe - only relevant in the way it may define the join. In your example, there's some logic that says "records that match on ID should also fit within a date range" for the join to be valid".

The use case where you'd include the comparison in the join statement is where the business domain suggests these records belong together only when the entire join condition is met.

The use case where you'd include the comparison in the where clause is where it refines the results you want, but doesn't define which records "belong together" in the business domain.

Comment: So then by you saying that the two usages are equivalent, that there is no one special use case where you would use one over the other?

Comment: I've updated my answer. From an execution point of view, they are equivalent - it's really a coding style thing

Answer (score 1):

Offhand I can't think of any examples of two tables that would be naturally related by a relationship involving an inequality. It's still not too difficult to think of a queries that I might write that would take advantage of the ability to use them. Suppose I want to rank people by age. For simplicity just assume no ties.

```
select p.name, count(*) as age_rank
from people p inner join people p2 on p2.birth_date <= p.birth_date
group by p.name
```

Many of these tricks with self joins are no longer necessary with advanced SQL features like analytic functions.

You question seemed to focus on moving logical conditions between `from` and `where`. Once you start using outer joins you no longer have that freedom as the queries are no longer identical semantically.

Comment: This problem could be solved by sorting the people by their Birthdate. instead of doing a seemingly unnecessary self join. I'm trying to find a use case where it would be more beneficial/necessary to put the criteria in the FROM. Would your query have more of a benefit than doing it my way?

Comment: Well you can certainly sort the results and *see* the ranking but that doesn't provide you with data internally usable by the query itself. The consensus is that you only put logic related to the join in the join condition. The optimizer is generally good at organizing the execution plan itself as necessary. But optimization is the only reason I can think of that would have a benefit. See my note about outer join above.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` is ANSI syntax which you should use. Avoiding adding to your `WHERE` is the best if you can.

Also,
It is generally considered more readable, especially when you join lots of tables and can be easily replaced with an `OUTER JOIN` whenever a need arises.

In terms of performance, their is no differences.

Comment: Both queries are using an explicit `inner join`

Comment: yeap sorry was to fast to respond to this... edited to match the question

Comment: What reasons should i avoid putting the criteria in my where statement? Is it just personal preference/personal readability? Criteria for me has always been logically placed in the WHERE, and currently I have never run into an issue where the WHERE statement has become to complex to understand.

Comment: It seems you don't want to understand one thing: "The more explicit, the easier it is to understand and maintain." Using Where is less explicit than On since you group all criteria from table to table.
This is not a norm or personal preference since I also use per default WHERE statement out of habit, just a simple fact. If you never had complexity problem on your query I somewhat envy you :)

Comment: Ok I just got the case, a bug on a querry of another dev with 4 Inner join on 2 index part each plus 3/2 where clause dedicated to the joined table plus around 15 for the main table. It was a nightmare to understand which clause is to wich table. Needed an extra effort to sort everything in my head.